# Firefox upgrade breaks Ctrl-W and Ctrl-U keybindings

Tags: firefox

The Ubuntu upgrade for Firefox to version 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 broke the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> keybindings in all my edit controls.

Other people asking for "Emacs editor controls" have found [Firemacs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/) useful -- but Firemacs does not provide a `kill-word` or `kill-line` field to bind with. [Customize Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) is often recommended as another approach, but it too does not provide `kill-word` or `kill-line` commands in its settings window.

I'm running Natty (11.04) but I have a suspicion it has more to do with Firefox than with the specific distribution.

How do I get my `^W` and `^U` keybindings back?

**Update**

I have made a fresh install of Precise (12.04) -- while keeping my home directory's contents -- and Firefox 12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 also demonstrates this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem; enabling all my plugins one at a time has revealed that the problem only exists with the (otherwise excellent) [Vimperator plugin](http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator) enabled.

Disabling Vimperator fixes the text area, text field, and input boxes `^W` and `^U` handling but at the cost of removing all the keyboard shortcuts I am familiar with. High cost.